# Curl: How to insert value to a cookie?

Tags: linux, bash, cookies, curl

Ho to insert cookies value in curl? from firebug *request headers* I can see in the following

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gg792c2ktu6sch6n8q0udd94o0; was=1; uncheck2=1; uncheck3=1; uncheck4=1; uncheck5=0; hd=1; uncheck1=1"
```

I have tried the following:

```
curl http://site.com/ -s -L -b cookie.c -c cookie.c -d "was=1; uncheck2=1; uncheck3=1; uncheck4=1; uncheck5=0; hd=1; uncheck1=1" > comic
```

and the only thing i see in cookie.c is

```
PHPSESSID=gg792c2ktu6sch6n8q0udd94o0; was=1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass keys/values to `cURL` cookie, you need the `-b` switch, not `-d`.

For the forms `-d`, the data will be separated by `&` and not by `;` in your `curl` command.

So :

```
curl http://site.com/ \
    -s \
    -L \
    -b cookie.c \
    -c cookie.c \
    -b "was=1; uncheck2=1; uncheck3=1; uncheck4=1; uncheck5=0; hd=1; uncheck1=1"
    > comic
```

If you need to know the names of the forms to be `POST`ed, you can run the following command :

```
mech-dump --forms http://site.com/
```

It comes with `libwww-mechanize-perl` package with `debian` or derivated.

Comment: `-d ` option is not to pass any cookie value but to POST forms ! If you need to modify the cookie, you should pass `-b key=value`